# Angular black page behind nginx and kubernetes

Tags: angular, kubernetes, minikube, nginx-ingress

I am trying to deploy my microservice application on Kubernetes using minikube. I have an angular front service and two backend services and I used this configuration to lunch deployment and services

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: searchservice
  labels:
    app: searchservice
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: searchservice
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: searchservice
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: searchservice
        image: ayoubdali/searchservice:0.1.9-SNAPSHOT
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8070
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: searchservice
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: searchservice
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
   # Port accessible inside cluster
    port: 8070
   # Port to forward to inside the pod
    targetPort: 8070
    nodePort: 31000

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: searchappfront
  labels:
    app: searchappfront
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: searchappfront
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: searchappfront
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: searchappfront
        image: ayoubdali/searchappfront:0.6.5
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: searchappfront
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: searchappfront
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    nodePort: 80

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: subscriberservice
  labels:
    app: subscriberservice
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: subscriberservice
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: subscriberservice
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: subscriberservice
        image: ayoubdali/subscriber-service:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT 
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8090
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: subscriberservice
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: subscriberservice
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 8090
    #targetPort: 80
    nodePort: 31102
```

and this configuration for the ingress service

```
 apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1 # for versions before 1.14 use extensions/v1beta1
 kind: Ingress
 metadata:
   name: ingress
   annotations:
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
 spec:
   rules:
   - host: app.info
     http:
       paths:
       - path: /
         backend:
           serviceName: searchappfront
           servicePort: 80
       - path: /api
         backend:
           serviceName: subscriberservice
           servicePort: 8090
```

But when I open app.info/ I got a blank page with javascript error like

```
Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

I tried deploying the application using docker compose and it works fine.

Comment: does your api needs to receive the request with the prefix `/api` or as `/` ? can you give me a correct request and response example?

Comment: Yes the subscriberservice receive all requests with the prefix ```/api/*``` like this one 
 ```/api/test/all``` . When I make subscriberservice as a nodePort I successfully receive data using Postman but when I use ingress I got ```404 not found```. For the ```\``` it points to the angular application but I receive a blank page with js file loading errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you enable  [`rewrite-target`](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/) it will create a capture group and send it to the appropriate service.

If you set the capture group to `$1`, everything after the root `/` will be discarted and the request is forwarded to root `path`.

- In order to forward the full request, **remove the `rewrite-target` line**, your Ingress should be like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
 kind: Ingress
 metadata:
   name: ingress
   annotations:
     kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
 spec:
   rules:
   - host: app.info
     http:
       paths:
       - path: /
         backend:
           serviceName: searchappfront
           servicePort: 80
       - path: /api
         backend:
           serviceName: subscriberservice
           servicePort: 8090
```

---

**Example:**

- I've deployed two `echo-apps` that echoes the requests, I've suppressed the output to show the path and the pod handling it on the background).

  - `echo1-app` is simulating `searchappfront`
  - `echo2-app` is simulating `subscriberservice`
- This is the ingress I'm using:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: echo-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
    - host: app.info
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: echo1-svc
              servicePort: 80
          - path: /api
            backend:
              serviceName: echo2-svc
              servicePort: 80
```

- Now let's test the commands:

```
$ kubectl get ingress
NAME           HOSTS      ADDRESS        PORTS   AGE
echo-ingress   app.info   35.188.7.149   80      73m

$ kubectl get pods
NAME                            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
echo1-deploy-764d5df7cf-2wx4m   1/1     Running   0          74m
echo2-deploy-7bcb8f8d5f-xlknt   1/1     Running   0          74m

$ tail -n 1 /etc/hosts
35.188.7.149 app.info

$ curl app.info
{"path": "/",
  "os": {"hostname": "echo1-deploy-764d5df7cf-2wx4m"}}

$ curl app.info/foo/bar
{"path": "/foo/bar",
  "os": {"hostname": "echo1-deploy-764d5df7cf-2wx4m"}}

$ curl app.info/api
{"path": "/api",
  "os": {"hostname": "echo2-deploy-7bcb8f8d5f-xlknt"}}

$ curl app.info/api/foo
{"path": "/api/foo",
  "os": {"hostname": "echo2-deploy-7bcb8f8d5f-xlknt"}}

$ curl app.info/api/foo/bar
{"path": "/api/foo/bar",
  "os": {"hostname": "echo2-deploy-7bcb8f8d5f-xlknt"}}
```

To summarize:

- Requests to **app.info/** will be delivered to `echo1-app` as **/**
- Requests to **app.info/foo/bar** will be delivered to `echo1-app` as **/foo/bar**
- Requests to **app.info/api** will be delivered to `echo2-app` as **/api**
- Requests to **app.info/api/foo/bar** will be delivered to `echo2-app` as **/api/foo/bar**

---

Considerations about your environment:

- I understand you are using `NodePort` to test the access, but if you wish to close that access, you can set the services as `ClusterIP` since it will be Ingress job to handle the incoming traffic.
- [Nodeport](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport) port range by default is 30000-32767.

  - `searchappfront` has it set to `80`, which will be ignored and the correct port will be attributed.

If you have any question let me know in the comments.